# How would this rails query be on sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to run something like this directly on mysql server database:

```
SupportRequest.all.map{ |support_request| SupportRequestFeedback.create(support_request_id: support_request.id) if support_request.support_request_feedback == nil}
```

I know the query it produces but not how to implemented in a 1 query command (with the loop)?

Comment: Could you be a bit clearer in your question? Do you mean you want to optimize the query or you want to know the SQL that would be generated? Or something else?

Comment: @oreoluwa I would like to know the query that this generates.

Answer (score 2):

You can enter this line in rails console to display queries:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

Then enter your code and the query will be displayed.

Comment: The query shows but only show the execution one by one. I would like a query that does everything in one command (in a loop)

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I don't think Rails provides a call to do this kind of operation at once.

You can setup a service to perform this for you, though:

```
support_requests_without_feedback = SupportRequest.includes(:support_request_feedback).where(support_request_feedback: {id: nil})
```

You could use the `active_record-import` gem to achieve mass db insert or you could use this: (not so effecient, though):

```
support_requests_without_feedback.map{|sr| sr.support_request_feedback.create }
```

Comment: I would like to be able to run a sql query command directly on the mysql console to achieve the same results, not on rails. The rails command is the one I posted on the initial post.